# where do I specify the canvas page/name? (not the canvas URL)

Tags: javascript, facebook-canvas

I am new to facebook apps, developing a simple Javascript app. I know I must be missing something big, but I can't see anywhere on the app settings where do specify the canvas page. all the screenshots I see online include it but not mine, I attached it here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Edit: For the `Page Tab` section to appear, click the white box that is under the Mobile and Devices section that says "I want to build a custom tab for Facebook pages".

The following has worked for me in the past:

`Website`: put the full URI without the filename and the domain in the site domain textbox:

```
Site URL: http://www.yoursite.com/subdomain/
Domain: yoursite.com
```

`App on Facebook`: put the same path as in the previous

```
Canvas URL: http://www.yoursite.com/subdomain/
```

(You will also need to add a https://... url by September I believe)

`Page Tab`: finally include the full URI with the file name

```
Page Tab Name: Your tab name
Page Tab URL: http://www.yoursite.com/subdomain/apage.html
```

Comment: I am sorry all the tutorials include filling in a field called "canvas name" and from your answer I still do not now where it is

Comment: Hi Stephane, what is the objective of the "canvas name"? Is it to give you the url: http://apps.facebook.com/canvas-name-here? If that is the case, you specify it in `App Namespace` and for the name (the title that will appear in the browser window), change `App Display Name`. Tutorials may be out of date.

Comment: Thanks indeed its App Namespace , facebook just recently changed the admin page and ALL the tutorial online are out of date.

Answer (score 0):

This is specified on [Getting Started › Apps on Facebook › Canvas Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/)

> To set up your Canvas Page and Canvas URL you must first register your Facebook app and enter in your basic app information. *Add an App Namespace to create a **Canvas Page** URL.*

Also when you click on the [?] next to App Namespace when editing your application it also says

> Namespace for your app used for Open Graph and **Canvas Page** (if applicable)